# Ive just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 same issue: no Menu, No launcher, but no Unity checkbox in ccsm

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, launcher, unity-dash

Using my Toshiba Satellite L350D I just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and now I don't have access to Launcher or top Menu bar. I've tried to follow the solutions both here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

When I try to activate Unity plugin there's no checkbox beside it in ccsm, its the only icon in the list without a checkbox so I cant enable it.. Any Ideas?

Comment: Add detail: Are you able to identify the graphics chipset? *You may need to update (using text mode), or load an additional video driver.*

Comment: Have you clicked the setting and looked in the window following that? On the left there is a sidebar and an item will be on the lower part giving you the option to enable the plugin, from my experience.

Last time I had this error and tried to enable Unity this way, it encountered many conflicts, I did my best to allow Unity to resolve the conflicts, even if it meant disabling some Compiz features.